# How to view our old questions that were deleted by community or by ourselves?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I want to view my old questions that are not present in my questions history. I don't remember whether they were deleted by myself or by the community. I want to use that question's logic in my new project, but that question exists nowhere.

Comment: Your most recently deleted Q is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40576246/how-do-i-get-a-page-instance-from-its-child-user-control) - not sure if that's the one you're after?

Comment: @AndrewT. I'm guessing you didn't mean to link to this post in your comment? :)

Comment: @JonClements oops! Should be the [10k rep privilege help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)... >_<

Comment: Failing a way to find it through [so], you could always try checking if you can find it in your browser history.

Comment: FWIW, I've always kinda wished for a `deleted.stackoverflow.com` that was easily searchable; I know SO curates content and deletes posts by design, but I wish I could "opt in" to searching deleted content as well as active content. The way the Roomba works [even one downvote or the view equation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) can delete an unanswered question;  sometimes the stuff I search for is so obscure and poorly documented that I'd take something even barely comprehensible over nothing, it'd probably still be better than forums.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have at least 10k reputation, you can use the search operator `deleted:1` to view your deleted posts.

If you have less than 10k reputation and your question was deleted less than 60 days ago, you can go to "Activity -> questions -> deleted recent questions".

If you have less than 10k reputation, and your questions was deleted more than 60 days ago, there's no direct way to find it. If you have a good reason to see it again, you can submit a custom moderator flag on one of your posts. A moderator will then review it and give you the link if necessary.

Comment: Do reputation entries for deleted posts remain in your reputation tab on your profile? Not a reliable method by any means but if the answer is yes then it remains a *possible* method, though time-consuming.

Comment: @TylerH no. If the post is less than 60 days old when it's deleted, any reputation changes from the post are lost. If it is older than 60 days, I suppose you can use that method. It would be very inefficient though, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Sure, I hadn't thought about the reversion of reputation; that's a good point. That kicks in if the question had less than 3 upvotes (or is it a total score of less than 3?) and is less than 6 months old when deleted.